# Using "that" before pronouns

Tags: grammar

I seem to have a problem with using the word "that" before pronouns and have been told that it is wrong.

Examples:

> 1. They were playing a piece of music that they had only heard once before.
> 2. I am going to a shop that I like.

Is it really wrong to put "that" before pronouns and if so, why is it wrong? 
What is the rule that goes with this?

Comment: It's not wrong. Who told you _that it is_? See what I did there?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: (1) there are several words _that_ in English, so saying _the word "that"_ is not helpful; this one is the complementizer _that_. (2) English has no rules forbidding complementizers to appear before pronouns (in fact, it has no rules forbidding any kind of word to appear before any other kind of word -- the idea is silly in itself. (3) complementizer _that_ is often optional, and may be dropped or retained, as the speaker chooses. (4) since complementizer _that_ occurs at the beginning of the clause, it precedes the subject, which may be a pronoun.  But there's no rule about it.

Comment: There are two 'thats' involved here, and they are being confused. (1) The demonstrative determiner (cf 'this') ('I like that view / film / piece of music ...'); this cannot be used before say _him_ or _them_ (though 'I like that one' is fine). The complementiser 'that' may be used before nouns or pronouns in the subjective case (I think that John / Sue / the dog / he / they / it ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth .. Yes, and before "accusative" case ones too!

Comment: @Araucaria I'm struggling to find an example that doesn't sound outlandish. 'I think that him being picked was wrong' sounds acceptable, but I'd rephrase.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe " I think that them being so sensitive works against me",. What d'you reckon?

Comment: I'd use the poss-ing there.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post by Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-leave-out-that),

> When you’re deciding whether to keep or omit your that, you need to consider how your sentence flows. Many times, it’s just a matter of personal preference. Some people think adding that improves the flow of the sentence and makes it easier for the reader to understand. Others believe they should delete every seemingly unnecessary that because they want to maintain an economy of words. I’m all for cutting unnecessary words, but I often like to keep my that if it helps the rhythm of the sentence.

She goes on to give examples of when to definitely use *that* and when definitely not to.

Comment: Grammar Girl is very nice, but her grammar advice is -- alas -- incomplete, often unreliable, and not free of zombie rules. She's not a grammarian; she's a blogger.

Answer (score 0):

It's not technically wrong. I think function of `that` you are referring to is that of a noun clause as described on [this](http://www2.gsu.edu/~eslhpb/grammar/lecture_13/that.html) page under §5. However, to me it tends to sound a bit odd if somebody does this consistently.

I'm Dutch and in Dutch the usage of the word `that` in cases like these is very common. So this is one of the telltale signs of a fellow native Dutchman speaking english:).

Disclaimer: I sometimes find, I tend to think anything that sounds Dutch isn't proper English. So I might be slightly biased on this one:).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is wrong per se. I am not an expert. But I am fairly sure that in the first example you gave, the word "that" is not needed in the sentence. You could simply remove it.
"They were playing a piece of music they had only heard once before."

The second example also seems to me that it does not need the word "that"
"I am going to a shop I like."

Someone correct me if I'm wrong on that. But I believe your usage of the word "that" seems perfectly acceptable, just unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

*That* can serve as a **[syntactic pleonasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Syntactic_pleonasm)**, which "occurs when the grammar of a language makes certain function words optional" (Wikipedia). Therefore, both of the following sentences are grammatically correct:

> - I know you are coming.
> - I know that you are coming.

It's a matter of personal preference whether you leave *that* in or take it out; the sentences you gave will be grammatically correct either way.

Comment: There are some rules -- _that_ is required when it introduces a subject complement clause; otherwise you can't tell the dependent from the independent clause. _That he left early turned out to be a blessing_, but not **He left early turned out to be a blessing*.